# Upload Image to Sharepoint Photo Library from asp.net mvc

Tags: sharepoint-addin, asp.net, client-object-model, picture-library, mvc

I have a Provider Hosted App, one of it's functionality is to upload the images into sharepoint picture library.

I am able to store the picture into some folder, using the below code.

```
public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {

        var hostweb = HttpContext.Request["SPHostUrl"];
        Helper.WriteLog(hostweb);
        Uri hosturi = new Uri(hostweb);

        using (var clientContext = new ClientContext(hosturi))
        {
            //List Photos = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Photos");

            var fileinfo = new FileCreationInformation();               
            fileinfo.Content = Helper.ReadFully(file.InputStream);
            //This will convert the Input Stream to byte[]

            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);                
            var path = Path.Combine("E:/Photos", fileName);
            file.SaveAs(path);
            Helper.WriteLog(path);
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Now I want to store the Image to the Photos Library. How should I do it.

Answer (score 2):

This is what we are supposed to do.

```
public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {

        var hostweb = HttpContext.Request["SPHostUrl"];           
        Uri hosturi = new Uri(hostweb);

        using (var clientContext = new ClientContext(hosturi))
        {    
            using (var fs = file.InputStream)
            {
                var fi = new FileInfo(file.FileName);
                //change fi.name so that it is unique
                var list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Photos");
                clientContext.Load(list.RootFolder);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                var fileUrl = String.Format("{0}/{1}", list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl, fi.Name);

                Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect(clientContext, fileUrl, fs, true);                    
            }
        }
        return View();
    }
```